# Questions about simple python script

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a homework assignment, to write a simple grocery list, the is script should be able to:

1. Accept user input of variables such as item_name, quantity, and cost of an item
2. Using the information gathered from the user, create a dictionary entry and add it to a list called grocery_history
3. Print out all the items entered in the following format: Variable →  number  name        price       item_total
4. And finally output the grand total of the cost of all the items

This is my code:

```
grocery_item = {}
grocery_history=[{}]
stop = 'go'
item_name = input("Item name:")
quantity = input("Quantity purchased:")
cost = input("Price per item:") 
grocery_history.append(item_name)
grocery_history.append(quantity)
grocery_history.append(cost)

cont = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:")
while cont != 'q':
  item_name = input("Item name:")
  quantity = input("Quantity purchased:")
  cost = input("Price per item:") 
  cont = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:")


  grocery_history.append(item_name)
  grocery_history.append(quantity)
  grocery_history.append(cost)



grand_total = []

number = grocery_history[quantity]
price = grocery_history[cost]

for grocery_history in grocery_item:    
  item_total = int(number)*float(price)
  grand_total.append(item_total)
   print(grocery_history[number][name] + "@" [price]:.2f + "ea'.format(**grocery_item)")     


item_total = 0


print ("Grand total:" + str(grand_total))
```

at my  `number = grocery_history[quantity]`
    price = grocery_history[cost]`statement I get a`Key Error 2`, and I'm not sure why, the keys should exist, but maybe they are not being added to the list properly. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated, if you need more details let me know and I will edit them in.

Comment: It seems that `grocery_history` is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: You are trying to access a list with a key (str). It can't work.

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example (explanation following):

```
grocery_history={'item_name':[], 'quantity':[], 'cost':[]}
cont = 'c'
while cont != 'q':
    item_name = input("Item name:")
    quantity = int(input("Quantity purchased:"))
    cost = int(input("Price per item:"))
    cont = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:")

    grocery_history['item_name'].append(item_name)
    grocery_history['quantity'].append(quantity)
    grocery_history['cost'].append(cost)


grand_total = 0
for i in range(len(grocery_history['item_name'])):
    item_name = grocery_history['item_name'][i]
    quantity = grocery_history['quantity'][i]
    cost = grocery_history['cost'][i]

    priceTimesQuantity = quantity * cost
    grand_total = grand_total + priceTimesQuantity
    message = 'Bought {} x{} (each: {}$) to a total of: {}'.format(item_name, quantity, cost, priceTimesQuantity)
    print( message )

finalmessage = 'Grand Total: {}'.format(grand_total)
print(finalmessage)
```

---

1. I reduced the part above your first loop (think about it)
2. `grocery_history` is now a dictionary containing 3 lists. example:
   [image]
3. we now fill this these lists downwards with the items (`append`)
4. when the user is finished, we go trough that lists again with `i` as index 
   (see the little gray number on the left side of the image)
   Then, for every item we load the details from the list and calculate the price in total
   Furthermore, we are adding the total to the `grand_total`, which is a number (starting from zero) adding up with the second loop.
5. after the second loop is done we print the final value (sum)

---

in the Texts : `"some text {}".format(var)` - `{}` is a placeholder for the `var` coming after the string

Answer (score 0):

Your grocery_history is a list of dictionaries. When you create an entry in grocery_history, you just add simple values to a list, not dictionaries.

Parsing a list should not be a problem if you know the exact size of each of your elements, but a more elegant solution would be to create another object inside the list that properly describes a grocery.

```
grocery_item = {}
grocery_history=[{}]
stop = 'go'
item_name = input("Item name:")
quantity = input("Quantity purchased:")
cost = input("Price per item:")
# We define each grocery as a dictionary containing the key "item_name" and values formed by another dict
# that is made up of keys "quantity" and "cost" with their respective values
# Each grocery will look like this {'grocery_name': {'quantity': 2.5, 'cost': 21.44}}
groceries = {item_name: {'quantity': float(quantity), 'cost': float(cost)}}
grocery_history.append(groceries)

cont = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:")
while cont != 'q':
  item_name = input("Item name:")
  quantity = input("Quantity purchased:")
  cost = input("Price per item:")
  cont = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:")
  groceries = {item_name: {'quantity': float(quantity), 'cost': float(cost)}}
  grocery_history.append(groceries)

total = 0
for grocery in grocery_history:
  for name, properties in grocery.items():
    total+= properties['quantity']*properties['cost']

print('Total of groceries is: ', total)
```